# Bash file with a .bat extension gets an unrecognized command error

Tags: windows, bash

I literally started playing with BASH today.

I have the following file:

```
echo "Please enter some input: "
read input_variable
echo "You entered: $input_variable"
```

I have saved the file as `batchFile.bat`.

When I run the batch file it just closes almost immediately, with some testing I pulled out the following error:

> 'read' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

How do I fix this? Not getting any luck with Google searches.

Comment: You might want to point out that you're apparently work under Windows. This works as is under Linux, I just tried it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.bat` is the extension for [batch files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file) executed by `cmd.exe`.

Bash scripts are different. As a pre-requisite you need to enable the [Windows Subsystem on Linux](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/faq). Then, to create a new script there are a couple of steps:

1. Create the file using a Linux-savvy text editor such as `vi` or `nano` so that it has UNIX line endings (LF). Notepad won't cut it as it only works with Windows line endings (CRLF).
2. Put `#!/bin/bash` at the top.
3. Run `chmod +x script.sh` to make the script executable.

These are the same steps you'd follow in Linux, for what it's worth.

Comment: Yes, use the same steps in Cygwin.